# Why does my for work in the commandline but not my batch script

Tags: batch-file

When I run the following line in cmd.exe consol it works.

```
FOR /d /r ./ %d IN (*Images) DO @IF EXIST "%d" RD /s/q "%d"
```

When I paste the same line in my batch script it says:

```
d" RD /s/q "d" was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: Because you did not read the help file for the command you are using. This would have taken you all of 15 seconds to read as it is at the top of the help file. `To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To use the `FOR` command in a batch program, specify `%%variable` instead of `%variable`**.

`for /?` says on the first screen (9th line):

```
==> for /?
Runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.

FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

  %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
  (set)      Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.
  command    Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
  command-parameters
             Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.

To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
from %I.
```